# PHP and ajax communication is not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

Below are my code : I want to retrieve the data from database using php and using raw javaScript I am not getting any error on screen but the result won't show on the div element .Kindly let me know what is wrong here.

HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    User<input type="text" name="enterText" id="enterText">
    <input type="button" value="click" id="btn">
    <div id="dvID"></div>
    <script src="sendData.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code :

```
var xhr;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
 xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}
var jsonData= "";
 xhr.onreadystatechange =function()
 {
  if(xhr.readystate==4)
 {
    console.log("in ready state");
    if(xhr.success >=200&& xhr.success <300)
    {
        consle.log("in sucess");
        jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        document.getElementIdById("dvID").innerHTML = jsonData;
        console.log("after jsonData "+jsonData);
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementIdById("dvID").innerHTML = "it's not success ";
    }
    }
}
var element1 = document.getElementById("dvID") ;
console.log(element1);
xhr.open("POST","index.php");
var element = document.getElementById("btn") ;
if(element)
{
element.addEventListener('click',function(){
console.log("just clicked")
xhr.send(document.getElementById("dvID").value);
```

})
  }

and here is my Php code :

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
mysql_connect($dbhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db("trynew") or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST["enterText"])) {
$user = $_POST['enterText'];
echo $user;
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM trynewtable where name = '$user' ";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result==FALSE)
{
die(mysql_error());
}

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$jsondata = json_encode($row);
echo $jsondata;
mysql_close();
?>
```

I tried with both POST and GET method but nothing's working.

There was a bug i changed the data that I am sending to php "xhr.send(document.getElementById("enterText").value);" but still there's nothing on the screen

Comment: There are a few little errors - in the ajax function you should use `if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 ){` rather than `xhr.success` - you are using the deprecated and unsafe `mysql` functions, change to `mysqli` or `PDO` and I'd suggest creating a reusable ajax function which can be used for different purposes by changing the parameters used rather than writing the whole thing again

Comment: "@mysql_select_db() ", em theres no @ in php in that case

Comment: And theres no "enterText" posted to your php

Comment: @Jonasw The `@` suppresses errors

Comment: You didn't set a content type for your ajax post, PHP's $_POST expects application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data. Ind your send you select the div to send the value instead of the input and you have to send it in key=pair values.

Comment: `$_POST["enterText"]` is not set. Your query will always fail, you should move the query into the conditional. This also is open to SQL injections.

Comment: I changed to the text value from div that I am sending

Answer (score 0):

To get you started with a reusable ajax function and mysqli

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        if( !empty( $_POST['enterText'] ) ){
            ob_clean();

            /* empty placeholder array for json data */
            $output=array();

            $text=$_POST['enterText'];

            /* db connection using mysqli */
            $dbhost =   'localhost';
            $dbuser =   'root'; 
            $dbpwd  =   'xxx';
            $dbname =   'trynew';

            /* create the connection */
            $db = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

            /* create the sql with a placeholder rather than embedded variables! */
            $sql='select * from `trynewtable` where `name`=?;';


            $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bind_param( 's', $text );
            $res=$stmt->execute();

            if( $res ){
                /* Bind EACH field referenced in query and in recordset here!!! */
                $stmt->bind_result( $id, $user );
                /* Number of fields in recordset = number of bound variables! */

                /* Fetch the data */
                $stmt->fetch();

                /* Add data to output - to be sent as json data */
                $output=array( 
                    'id'        =>  $id,
                    'username'  =>  $user
                );
            }
            /* tidy up */
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
            $db->close();

            /* send the response to the ajax callback function */
            header( 'Content-Type: application/json', true, 200 );
            exit( json_encode( $output ) );
        }


    }

?>  

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Got to have a title</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>

            /* basic reusable ajax function */
            function ajax(m,u,p,c,o){
                /*
                    m=method,u=url,p=params {n:v},c=callback,o=options {n:v}
                */
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 )c.call( this, xhr.response, o, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() );
                };

                var params=[];
                for( var n in p )params.push(n+'='+p[n]);

                switch( m.toLowerCase() ){
                    case 'post':
                        p=params.join('&');
                    break;
                    case 'get':
                        u+='?'+params.join('&');
                        p=null;
                    break;  
                }

                xhr.open( m.toUpperCase(), u, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.send( p );
            }


            /* create instance of the ajax function */
            function bindEvents(e){
                document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){ /* this is where you set the different parameters, here we POST `enterText` */
                    ajax.call( this, 'post', document.location.href, { enterText:document.getElementById('enterText').value }, callback, { dvID:document.getElementById('dvID') } )
                }, false );
            }

            /* callback function to process response from PHP script */
            function callback(r,o,h){
                if( r ){
                    /* */
                    var json=JSON.parse(r);

                    /* use the callback to process the json data */
                    o.dvID.innerHTML='Response:'+r;
                }
            }

            /* bind event listeners */
            document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents, false );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        User: <input type="text" name="enterText" id="enterText">
        <input type="button" value="click" id="btn">
        <div id="dvID"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```